# variable in web service operation not being updated

Tags: java, web-services, rest, variables, exception

I am creating a very simple web service example with java. I have a variable num initialized to 0, but I am not able to retain its value at the end.
Its value should be incremented by 1 as per the DB I have.

Here is the web service operation:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getNewID")
public String getNewID(@WebParam(name = "newID") String txt2) 
{
Connection connection = null;  
ResultSet resultSet = null;  
Statement statement = null;
int num=0;
    try 
        {  
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/java/db/test.sqlite");  
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM LOGINDETAILS where ID = '"+txt2+"'");

            while (resultSet.next()) 
                {  
                    //System.out.println("Your ID "+ resultSet.getString("ID"));
                    num++;
                }

        } 

    catch (Exception e) 
        {  
            System.out.println("You had an exception");
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }

    finally 
        {  
        try 
            {  
                resultSet.close();  
                statement.close();  
                connection.close();  
            } 
        catch (Exception e) 
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        } 
    if(num==0)
        { 
            return "Your ID does not match";
        }

    else
        {
            return "Welcome "+txt2;
        }
}
```

In the output I am getting

Method returned
java.lang.String : "Your ID does not match"

For all the cases only the if part is working and not the else. When i tried the same method inside a class its working fine, but not in case of web service operation

New code

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getNewID")
public String getNewID(@WebParam(name = "newID") String txt2) 
{
String str = null;
Connection connection = null;  
ResultSet resultSet = null;  
Statement statement = null;
    int num=0;
    try 
        {  
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/java/db/test.sqlite");  
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM LOGINDETAILS where ID = '"+txt2+"'");

            while (resultSet.next()) 
                {  
                    //System.out.println("Your ID "+ resultSet.getString("ID"));
                    num++;
                }

        } 

    catch (Exception e) 
        {  
            System.out.println("You had an exception");
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }

    finally 
        {  
        try 
            {  
                resultSet.close();  
                statement.close();  
                connection.close();  
            } 
        catch (Exception e) 
            {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        } 
    assert num == 0 || txt2 == null : str = "num "+num+"txt2 "+txt2;
    return str;

    /*if(num==0)
        { 
            return "Your ID does not match Please Try Again Or if new user then please register";
        }

    else
        {
            return "Welcome "+txt2;
        }*/
}
```

In the result I am getting the value of str as null.

Ok I tried this now ..

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getNewID")

public String getNewID(@WebParam(name = "newID") String txt2) 
{
Connection connection = null;  
ResultSet resultSet = null;  
Statement statement = null;
int num=0;
    try 
        {  
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");  
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:src/java/db/test.sqlite");  
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT ID FROM LOGINDETAILS where ID = '"+txt2+"'");

            while (resultSet.next()) 
                {  
                    num++;
                }
            return resultSet.toString();

        } 

    catch (Exception e) 
        {  
            System.out.println("You had an exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "You had an exception";
        }


}
```

I am getting the output

```
java.lang.String : "You had an exception"
```

When its working fine outside the web service operation then why its showing an exception here... and how can I correct it ?

Comment: Check if your code encountered an exception or if the result set is empty by debugging it. Also your code could leak connections if establishing the connection succeeds but there are errors in statement execution. `resultSet` could be null for example. Then there is also the possibility of SQL injection because your queries are not parametrized.

Comment: But the same code is working fine when I am using it inside a normal class. The else part is working there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check for exceptions
2. Debug the code via debugger, assert statements or if you really need to   `System.out.println` statements.
3. If you are able, run the query against the db first and see if you get the expected result.
4. Make sure the class for the driver that is being loaded loads properly. Make sure the lib is in the class path.

Regards Rentius

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done all the above things and there is no issue..I am also getting the expected output while querying against the db...I did not get "assert statements" .. Can you explain pls

Comment: Assert statements is used to test i.e "assert expression". In your case you can write 'assert num == 0 || txt2 == null'. Remember when you run the application you need to tell it to enable assert statement. Add the following to the vm arguments "-ea". It will run the assert when it reaches the assert statement and will show an error when the condition is false "AssertError", check the log.

Comment: Make sure that when connecting to the db that you are using the same schema. i.e in db2 you connect to the db with DB2ADMIN and when you do the query on the db it does it against DB2ADMIN. When you connect to a db from the outside it might not be actually querying against the DB2ADMIN schema. Just make sure yours is correct.

Comment: Ok .. I tried getting the values of both these variables..I added a String variable str and in the end I inserted the code..
"assert num == 0 || txt2 == null : str = "num "+num+"txt2 "+txt2;  return str; "
 ... in place of the if else condition
And the output I get
java.lang.String : "null"

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code where you did this? and the result please.

Comment: In the same project I placed a class with the same method functionality and its working fine..The outputs are all expected..My db file is placed in the project folder itself.